# Informatica Workflow Only Loading One Target Row

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a workflow in Informatica with 261 records in the source table and am trying to load into another. However, the workflow only loads one row. The workflow Task Details show that all 261 records were successfully extracted from the source table, but only one row is inserted into the target. The session log didn't seem to be very helpful. I feel like the issue is an option flag or check-box I'm missing somewhere. Here's a section of the session log:

[image]

How can I set up the workflow so that all records are loaded?

*** Screenshot UPDATE ***

[image]

Comment: Looks like some aggregation to me. Please try enabling "Collect performance data" on session Properties tab. Then run the workfow and in the Workfow Monitor double-click the session (or choose "Get Run Properties") and in the details window expand the "Performance" node < this needs to be done DURING the session run. Next try to analyze the counts per transformation or paste a screenshot here.

Comment: @Maciejg It was an aggregator issue. I deleted the Aggregator and it worked. Unfortunately, I do need the aggregator so I'm gonna have to figure out how to use it without the issue but thanks.

Comment: This means the Group By ports have been set wrong, i.e. on a port that has same values across all rows. Select appropriate ports for grouping and this should be fine. Feel free to ask any further questions if you'd need more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an aggregator issue. I edited the Group By ports so that they didn't have the same values across all rows.